# I don't know how to set firebase firestore.settings at case admin.firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want set option at admin.firestore, but I don't found set method.
like this

```
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots：true}
admin.firestore.settings(settings)
```

TypeError: Firestore.settings is not a function at .....

Comment: Use `admin.firestore().settings(settings)`

Comment: I asked a question here for the first time.

I am deeply moved by my very early reply.

I also thank you for revising it.

But I still get an error. .

`TypeError: admin.firestore(...).settings is not a function
    at...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
"firebase-admin": "^5.13.0",
"firebase-functions": "^1.1.0",
```

With the latest versions works fine for me:

```
const firestoreSettings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
const firestore = admin.firestore();

firestore.settings(firestoreSettings);
```

Comment: I did it!
Thank you!
I appreciate your early reply.
And I am deeply moved.

Comment: Can you give details on how to upgrade the firebase-admin?

Comment: To upgrade in android... go to projectDirectory > Functions > npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save

Comment: @JeffPadgett My particular way to do this is run _npm outdated_ to check the current vs latest version and then run _npm i package@version --save_ if you are interested.